# MDX Percentage Row Not Calculating Correctly

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am trying to calculate a percentage row in a table based on a total column derived earlier in the query.

There are two columns then I create a total for that column. In the next row I want a percentage of the total to show. The output should be something like:

---

```
               Life      Non-Life (P&C)      SumTotal
Premiums    66,104.44        916,792.51     982,896.95 
Percentage      6.73%            93.27%              1
```

---

But instead the second line shows zero.

How do I structure the query to calculate correctly?
Here is the mdx code:

```
with member [LocationSpecificClass].[Hierarchy].[All].&[Insurance Market Statistics].[SumTotal]  as  SUM([LocationSpecificClass].[Hierarchy].[All].&[Insurance Market Statistics] , [Measures].[Value]  ) 

member [LocationSpecificData].[Data Type].[All].[Percentage] as [LocationSpecificData].[Data Type].[All].[Gross Written Premiums Total - Calculated], [Measures].[Value] ) / ([LocationSpecificClass].[Hierarchy].[All].&[Insurance Market Statistics].[SumTotal], [Measures].[Value]  ) 

Select  { [LocationSpecificClass].[Hierarchy].[All].&[Insurance Market Statistics].&[Life], [LocationSpecificClass].[Hierarchy].[All].&[Insurance Market Statistics].&[Non-Life (P&C)],   [LocationSpecificClass].[Hierarchy].[All].&[Insurance Market Statistics].[SumTotal]  } On Columns , 
{   [LocationSpecificData].[Data Type].[All].[Gross Written Premiums Total - Calculated] ,    [LocationSpecificData].[Data Type].[All].[Percentage] } On Rows
FROM [CubeDatabase]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following example, which worked fine in my environment. I've used our date dimension `[Datum]` with the year attribute `[Jahr]` to add a second a line by adding `[Line2]`. The first shown line is the year 2016. Set the calculated measures [M1] and [M2] to your needs and exchange the year dimension accordingly.

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[M1] AS [Measures].[name of your measure for col 1]
MEMBER [Measures].[M2] AS [Measures].[name of your measure for col 2]
MEMBER [Measures].[Total] AS [Measures].[M1] + [Measures].[M2]

MEMBER [Datum].[Jahr].[Line2] AS
    Divide(
        ([Datum].[Jahr].&[2016], [Measures].CurrentMember),
        ([Datum].[Jahr].&[2016], [Measures].[Total])
    )

SELECT {
    [Measures].[M1],
    [Measures].[M2],
    [Measures].[Total]
} ON 0,

{
    [Datum].[Jahr].&[2016],
    [Datum].[Jahr].[Line2]
} ON 1

FROM [name of cube]
```

The result in my environment looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks heaps.

Comment: You're welcome :) I have slightly updated the `[Line2]` calculation which is a better solution now.